# Is it possible to add a title to checkboxbuttongroup objects in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to create a dashboard with a number of RangeSlider and CheckboxButtonGroup widgets as filters for a ColumnDataSource object. I'm able to put a title on the RangeSliders but CheckboxButtonGroup objects don't have that attribute.

My examples are all from the widgets documentation: [link here for reference](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html)

[RangeSlider example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKD3E.png), [CheckboxButtonGroup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnp9G.png)

I thought name might be the right attribute but that doesn't appear to work as I thought. Is there some sort of approach someone has implemented to get similar functionality? Or would I just be better off using a MultiSelect as it has a title and similar function?

[MultiSelect example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCq63.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way of giving a CheckboxButtonGroup a title is creating a seperate text widget  (Div/Paragaph/PreText) and placing it above the CheckboxButtonGroup.

Comment: when you downvote, please comment why - i know this isn't the wanted answer to the question of P B, but it is the best answer to my knowledge, and it works. When you know a better solution post it.